# Did Putin exclusively ban western food, or are Asian imports also prohibited?

Tags: russian-federation, trade, food

Remember when Putin did that thing of banning western food from Russia, and having all currently imported food destroyed. Well, just curious; is that sudden bout of protectionism still in effect? And did/does it affect non-western markets? Like Asian imports from Japan or China?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> did/does it affect non-western markets?

They have banned food originated **from only the countries that have imposed sanctions** after the Russia's armed invasion to Ukraine.

2014: [This page](http://www.eurofoodlaw.com/policy/trade/list-of-products-banned-by-russia-with-custom-codes-102084.htm) lists the products originally banned in 2014:
*The products, banned **if they originate from the EU, US, Australia, Norway or Canada***

2015: Then, along with more countries joined the sanctions, the list was extended: *Prime Minister Dmitry Medvedev said the ban would now apply to **Iceland, Liechtenstein, Albania and Montenegro**.* — [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-33905340)

> Like Asian imports from Japan or China?

**Japan**: [this article](http://in.rbth.com/news/2016/10/31/japans-prime-minister-says-tokyo-will-maintain-sanctions-against-russia_643643) suggests that *Tokyo will maintain sanctions against Russia*, so probably yes.

**China** has not imposed sanctions on Russia, so there is no food ban.

---

> is that sudden bout of protectionism still in effect?

**Yes.**
June 2016: *"Russia prolongs Western food embargo until end of 2017"* — [Russia Today](https://www.rt.com/business/348916-putin-prolongs-food-embargo/)

November 2016: Putin said that *Russia's ban on Western foods will last 'as long as possible'*  — [Russia Today](https://www.rt.com/news/367805-putin-west-food-ban/)

November 2020: "Russian President Vladimir Putin on Saturday extended an embargo on Western food imports introduced in 2014 until the end of 2021, an economic measure that mainly affects EU imports." — [The Moscow Times](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2020/11/21/russia-extends-western-food-imports-embargo-to-end-2021-a72112)

Comment: Original text: http://government.ru/docs/14195/